# java -version, question about three different result lines

Tags: java, version

I have been programming in Java for a while but actually never cared too much about versioning. But now I checked the version (with "java -version") and I get three lines and I do not understand the difference. I am familiar with the concepts JRE, JDK and JVM but I am not sure about what those three lines are. I actually get:

```
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

What does each line mean? And why can they show different versions? I tried this in another computer and all three lines show different versions.
I checked the forum and found related Q&A but they do not tackle this particular issue.

Cheers!

Comment: Good Question actually. The [documentation for `java` tool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) says virtually nothing: *`-version` Prints product version to the error stream and exits.*

Answer (score 2):

It has the information about java version, edition, and runtime environment.
For more details refer to [*J2SE SDK/JRE Version String Naming Convention*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/versioning-naming.html).